# Pegar Dados na estrutura JSON com python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, getjson

Quero acessar determinada informação no código JSON abaixo, com python:

```
{
  "informacao1": valor_informação1,
  "informacao2": "{
    dado=informação_dado
}"

print(arquivojson.get("informacao1"))
```

O print acima vai exibir a linha abaixo.

Exibição:

> > valor_informação1

Como acessar o valor de **dado=**?

Tentei o comando abaixo, porém não funciona

```
print(arquivojson.get("informacao1").get("dado"))
```

Comment: O JSON está exatamente da forma que colocou? Porquê o dado ali é uma string e não está num formato do JSON. Para obter essa informação você terá que tratar a string, com regex, por exemplo.

Comment: Está dessa forma, entendi, não tem outra forma de capturar esse valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da forma que está, a estrutura do seu dado está, aparentemente, inconsistente. Como comentado pelo Sidon, se utilizado JSON, um formato que faria muito mais sentido seria:

```
{
  "informacao1": "valor_informação1",
  "informacao2": {
    "dado": "informação_dado"
  }
}
```

Se você tem autonomia sobre o código que gera este JSON, recomendaria que fizesse esta alteração. Caso contrário, partindo do pressuposto que a informação está no formato desejado ou que você não tem como modificá-lo, você pode obter a informação assim:

Considere os dados de entrada:

```
content = '''{
  "informacao1": "valor_informação1",
  "informacao2": "{dado=informação_dado}"
}'''
```

Analisando o JSON, convertendo para um objeto Python:

```
data = json.loads(content)
```

Se fizermos:

```
print(data.get("informacao2"))
```

Teremos a saída:

```
{dado=informação_dado}
```

Para obter apenas o conteúdo após o `=`, podemos encontrar o índice dentro da *string* deste caractere e retornar a parte da mesma desta posição até o penúltimo caractere:

```
part = slice(data.get("informacao2").index("=") + 1, -1)
```

Neste caso, se você fizer `print(part)`, verá que ele vale `slice(6, -1, None)`, ou seja, retornará as posições da *string* entre o índice 6 até o penúltimo caractere.

```
dado = data.get("informacao2")[part]
```

Desta forma, `dado` valerá `informação_dado`.

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IJrz/1).

---

Considerando que `informacao2` seja algo como:

```
"{dado=informação_dado, dado2=informação_dado2, dado3=informação_dado3}"
```

Você pode obter todos os valores de `dados` através de expressão regular:

```
groups = re.findall(r"(?:dado\d*\=)(.*?)(?:[,}])", data.get("informacao2"))
```

Neste caso, ao fazer `print(groups)`, teremos:

```
['informação_dado', 'informação_dado2', 'informação_dado3']
```

Ou seja, uma lista com todos os dados da *string*. Para pegar o último valor, basta fazer `groups[-1]`.

Comment: Agradeço muito sua ajuda, o arquivo realmente está mal estruturado AndersonCarlosWoss e Sidon.
Estou tendo problemas em seu slice, pois tenho muitos registros dentro de "informacao2" e preciso capturar o ultimo registro, o arquivo está semelhantemente assim: 
content = '''{
  "informacao1": "valor_informação1",
  "informacao2": "{dado=informação_dado, dado2=informação_dado2, dado3=informação_dado}"
}'''

Como nós podemos contar esses registro ate o último?

Comment: Você precisa apenas do último ou todos eles?

Comment: A principio apenas o último, porém seria muito difícil capturar outra informação no meio do arquivo?

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi adicionei um trecho ao final da resposta, veja se é isso.

Comment: com regex vai dar certo, vou tentar mais tarde, obrigado pelo auxilio!

Comment: Vc tem o arquivo json, certo? Então acho que o mais indicado seria faser um "programainha" para 'normalilza-lo" Isto não seria difícil.

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo deve ser assim:

```
{
  "informacao1": "valor_informação1",
  "informacao2": {
    "dado": "informação_dado"
}
}
```

Dessa forma, voce pode fazer:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('arquivo.json') as f:    
    data = json.load(f)

pprint (data)
{'informacao1': 'valor_informação1', 'informacao2': {'dado': 'informação_dado'}} 

print (data['informacao2'])
{'dado': 'informação_dado'}
```

> Agora vamos considerar que as duas chaves contenham apenas strings, então salve o arquivo assim:

```
{
  "informacao1": "valor_informação1",
  "informacao2": "{dado=informação_dado}"
}
```

Então vc pode fazer:

```
 pprint(data)
{'informacao1': 'valor_informação1', 'informacao2': '{dado=informação_dado}'}

pprint (data['informacao1'])
'valor_informação1'
```

Comment: Sidon, vide comentários, o valor de `informacao2` é uma string mesmo, não um objeto.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Ok, então é só salva-la como string e não como objeto, editei a resposta e acrescentei o exemplo.

Comment: Correto, mas o usuário quer extrair a informação após o caractere `=`. Algo como `data.get('informacao2').get('dado')`, retornando `informação_dado`, entende?

Comment: Mas não é esse o conceito json, json pressupõe uma chave e um valor sempre, para fazer isso que voce quer vc tem q gravar o arquivo de acordo com o meu primeiro exemplo e, para obter a valor da chave dado, faça: `print(data['informacao2']['dado'])`, entendeu? :-)

Comment: Exato. Tudo indica que o JSON foi gerado de forma incorreta, por isso não pode ser recuperado da forma tradicional. Seria necessário algo como [isso](https://repl.it/IJrz/0).

Comment: Se o json foi gravado errado então nao tem jeito tem que fazer alguma gambiara como a q vc apresenta. Se vc tem a solução para contornar, qual é o objetivo da pergunta?

Comment: Mas não sou autor da pergunta. Só estou te orientando que a sua resposta não resolve o problema solicitado e indicando que poderá editá-la se for do seu interesse. Não necessariamente esse código será gambiara. Depende do contexto, que desconhecemos.

Comment: Talvez o json não tenha sido gerado errado, talvez o autor da pergunta estivesse, ele proprio, "gerando" o json de forma equivocada. Foi isso que entendi com a pergunta, se for isso mesmo,  a minha resposta, além de solucionar o problema, esclarece a ele como realmente funciona o json. Como vc mesmo disse, sem deixar claro o contexto, fica complicado.

Comment: Agradeço sua ajuda Sidon, mas infelizmente o arquivo JSON está inconsistente e não consigo modifica-ló