# Pegar elemento usando json python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Estou usando o seguinte código para tentar pegar o que tá escrito dentro de `definition`, localizado em `list`

```
import requests
import json
word = "salut"
page = requests.get("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=" + word)
gotcha = page.json()
print(gotcha.get("list"))
```

Só que o problema é que eu não consigo de fato coletar a *string* dentro de `definition`

```
[{'definition': 'Informal French greeting, equivalent to the English "hi."', 'permalink': 'http://salut.urbanup.com/1076339', 'thumbs_up': 186, 'author': 'WeluvTwinkie', 'word': 'Salut', 'defid': 1076339, 'current_vote': '', 'example': '"Hey, there!"\r\n"Salut!"', 'thumbs_down': 28}, {'definition': 'A sly way of pronouncing the word [slut]; used to describe pretty, [nympho] ballerinas.', 'permalink': 'http://sa-lut.urbanup.com/1152075', 'thumbs_up': 13, 'author': 'Sheeba', 'word': 'Sa-lut', 'defid': 1152075, 'current_vote': '', 'example': 'My saaaaa-lut: Scott Lloyd Forward', 'thumbs_down': 57}]
```

Comment: No código você obteve apenas o valor de `list`, que retorna uma lista de dicionários. Pode editar a pergunta e descrever como tentou acessar `definition`, de fato?

Comment: Como digo na pergunta, o problema é que eu não consigo pegar o valor de definition, só consegui acessar os valores incluídos em lista... Ou seja, eu gostaria de coletar a informação de definition

Comment: Você sabe como acessar um valor em uma lista e em um dicionário?

Comment: Sim, em certos casos

Comment: Então, o retorno que você tem em `gotcha.get("list")` é uma lista com apenas um elemento, que é um dicionário. Você precisará acessar a posição na lista para obter o dicionário e, nele, acessar a chave que deseja.

Comment: Confuso, mas tentarei. Obrigado

Comment: Aliás, essa pergunta é a mesma que esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267746/como-usar-json-no-python

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar JSON no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267746/como-usar-json-no-python)

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso vc tem um dicionário. Vc pode usar um for pra percorrer o vetor e ler cada item pela chave. Salva essa lista em uma variável, `var` e imprime:

`for v in var:
    print(v['definition'])`