# Receber e ler um json com lista dentro, python

Tags: python

Boa tarde, estou usando a biblioteca reqparse, mas não sei se funciona

estou recebendo um json assim:

```
{
    "boletoPago": [
    {
        "numero_boleto" : 23564754,
        "valor_pago" : 350.00,
        "data_pagamento" : "2020-08-25"
    },
    {
        "numero_boleto" : 28965700,
        "valor_pago" : 180.00,
        "data_pagamento" : "2020-08-25"
    }
  ]
}
```

e preciso ler cada compo desses

usando um código assim ele só pega o primeiro cara da lista

```
argumentos = reqparse.RequestParser()
argumentos.add_argument("boletoPago", type = str, required =True)
        args = argumentos.parse_args()
        for v in args:
            print(args[v])
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206294/pegar-dados-na-estrutura-json-com-python Acho que isso deve te ajudar

Comment: não funciona, preciso ler a lista que está dentro do json e as chaves dentro das listas

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso lhe ajuda:

```
import json

with open('arquivo.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#Acessando as listas
data["boletoPago"]
```

Comment: puts Juan, isso não me ajuda muito, não se se é problema do reqparse, mas aparentemente não está recebendo a lista inteira, só a primeira posição dela, ou seja, não consigo ler a lista

Comment: Tente isso pra vê se da certo no `add_argument` use `type=list` e `location='json'`